# flutter dynamic form not working properly

Tags: flutter, forms, dart

in my app i wanted to create a group of dynamic forms in which the user can add more items. and in this dynamic form it consists two textfromfield (1) phone field (2) email field and one dropdownfield

[image: demo image here]

but anything I'm trying is not working properly. I've already asked for the fix on my code but got no answer. [stackoverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73931858/incremental-form-fields-in-flutter)  can anyone please refer me or show me a simpler way to acheive this?

Comment: why you generate controller ? you can achive it by using 1 general staefull widget. than every onchage save it as a string. 

so you are collecting the String value. not the controller

Comment: @pmatatias but how can i acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

this a little bit intermedite, but i think its ok. we are all need to learn somehing new.
i try to explain in a comment code. hope you understand.

copy this code, and run it on https://dartpad.dev/?

### Dynamic Form

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  /// all value are collected here.
  ///
  List<UserInfo> list = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Dynamic form"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          /// every time you add new Userinfo, it will generate new FORM in the UI
          list.add(UserInfo());
          setState(() {}); // dont forget to call setState to update UI
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          /// this is example display or access your value
          ///
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: ((context, index) => Text(list[index].phone))),
          ),

          /// this is your dynamic form
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                  return MyForm(
                    onRemove: () {
                      list.removeAt(index);
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    // dont forget use the key, to make sure every MyForm is has identity. to avoid missed build
                    key: ValueKey(index),
                    //pass init value so the widget always update with current value
                    initInfo: list[index],
                    // every changes here will update your current list value
                    onChangePhone: (phoneVal) {
                      if (phoneVal != null) {
                        list[index].setPhone(phoneVal);
                        setState(() {});
                      }
                    },
                    // every changes here will update your current list value
                    onchangeEmail: (emailVal) {
                      if (emailVal != null) {
                        list[index].setPhone(emailVal);
                        setState(() {});
                      }
                    },
                  );
                })),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final UserInfo initInfo;
  final Function(String?) onChangePhone;
  final Function(String?) onchangeEmail;
  final VoidCallback? onRemove;
  const MyForm(
      {super.key,
      required this.initInfo,
      required this.onChangePhone,
      this.onRemove,
      required this.onchangeEmail});

  @override
  State<MyForm> createState() => _MyFormState();
}

class _MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  TextEditingController _phoneCtrl = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _emailCtrl = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // set init value
    _phoneCtrl = TextEditingController(text: widget.initInfo.phone);
    _emailCtrl = TextEditingController(text: widget.initInfo.email);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: widget.onRemove, child: Text('Remove')),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _phoneCtrl,
            onChanged: widget.onChangePhone,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _emailCtrl,
            onChanged: widget.onchangeEmail,
          ),

          /// same like TextFormField, you can create new widget below
          /// for dropdown, you have to 2 required value
          /// the initValue and the onchage function
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// Create a class to make it easy access and
/// collectiing all your value
/// instead you have 3 different list,
/// you can just have 1 list object
class UserInfo {
  ///define
  String _phone = '';
  String _email = '';
  String _category = '';

  /// getter
  String get phone => _phone;
  String get email => _email;
  String get category => _category;

  ///setter
  void setPhone(String phone) {
    _phone = phone;
  }

  void setEmail(String email) {
    _email = email;
  }

  void setCategory(String category) {
    _category = category;
  }
}
```

Comment: does this code work only in flutter 2.8 and above? b/c i'm using fluter 2.5 and it has an error in the code `All final variables must be initialized, but 'initInfo', 'onChangePhone', and 1 others aren't.
Try adding initializers for the fields.` and also i run it in dartpad and the dropdown is not displaying

Comment: plus how can i control the value from dropdowns. for textfield i can use `TextEditingController()` but how can do it for dropdown?

Comment: @MohammedBekele, i havent create a dropdown in my example. you can create it, i had explain how to make it in the comment code

Comment: see my code, i dont control the Textfield, i pass the onchaged function.
same like dropdown, it has an onchanged function. use it like my example

Comment: i think for now most people usign flutter 2.17 - 3.0.0 , 
2.5.0  is still acceptable  the range.

but i suggest to upgrade to the latest stable version.

Comment: but for textfields you still passed the controllers and passed to onChanged. so for dropdown i have to pass the onchange, right?

Comment: thats right ...

Comment: so caw can i handle remove a form? i did a `onremove` in `MyForm` class and `onremove: () {
                        list.removeAt(index);
                        setState(() {});
                      }` but it didn't work.

Comment: updated my code, you can see it @MohammedBekele

Comment: one more thing happened tho, i added the forms and it works. but when i try to remove it removes the last index. for example if i had 3 forms and each has a value. and wanted to remove the 2nd form, it doesn't remove from the second it removes the last. but the value is correct. let me specify. {first, second, third} and if i remove the second form from list view the last one is removed but the value will be {first, third} and the list view value will be{first, second}